# How to use inner join on a MySQL table using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, inner-join

I have two tables like this:

**Employee**

```
EmployeeID  EmployeeName
1234        Jessica
1235        Tiffany
1236        Kayla
1237        Jackson
1238        Junior
1239        Ray
1240        Raymond
```

And...

**Form**

```
IDForm Form_EmployeeID Content AgreementBy  Verificationby  Validateby  receiver

1      1234            abcde   1235         1236            1237        1240

2      1238            dcbe    1235         1239            1237        1240
```

The problem is, I want to display a data like this:

I have tried use this code:

```
$id=$_GET['id'];

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT Employee.*, Form.*
                        FROM Form
                        INNER JOIN Employee ON Form.Form_EmployeeID= Employee.EmployeeID
                        where Form.FormID = '$id'") or die(mysql_error()); $data=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
```

But the data appears just like this:

```
Form ID        : 1
Employee Name  : Jessica
Content        : abcde
Agreement By   : 
Verification By: 
Validate By    : 
Received By    :
```

or like this:

```
 Form ID        : 1
Employee Name  : Jessica
Content        : abcde
Agreement By   : 1235
Verification By: 1236
Validate By    : 1237
Received By    : 1240
```

May I know where is the mistake?

Comment: Please use mysqli extension as mysql extension is deprecated.

Comment: you also need to join with other fields also as you inserted other ID's like `AgreementBy`  ,`Verificationby`   & etc

Comment: @Prafulla is right - you'll have to do a join for every relation column. Or just run a separate query to extract the employees you need once you get the form.

Comment: i have tried too but i got this message : Not unique table/alias: 'Employee'

Comment: @tara check my answer it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Query something like this...

```
SELECT Form.*, 
    a.EmployeeName as employee_name,
    b.EmployeeName as agreement_by,
    c.EmployeeName as verification_by,      
    d.EmployeeName as validate_by,
    e.EmployeeName as receiver_by
                    FROM Form
                    LEFT JOIN Employee a ON Form.Form_EmployeeID= a.EmployeeID
                    LEFT JOIN Employee b ON Form.AgreementBy= b.EmployeeID
                    LEFT JOIN Employee c ON Form.Verificationby= c.EmployeeID
                    LEFT JOIN Employee d ON Form.Validateby= d.EmployeeID
                    LEFT JOIN Employee e ON Form.receiver= e.EmployeeID
                    where Form.FormID = '$id'
```

Comment: i have tried this but i got this message --> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.EmployeeName as employee_name b.EmployeeName as agreement_by ' at line 2

Comment: I have edited now, I think comma is missing,, Please try with it...Thanks

Comment: yup that's right and it's works now. Once again thank you so much for our help

Answer (score 1):

Try this query and don't use **'*'** in select query...

```
 SELECT f.IDForm , f.Content ,
 emp1.EmployeeName as employee_name,
 emp2.EmployeeName as agreement_by,
 emp3.EmployeeName as verification_by ,      
 emp4.EmployeeName as validate_by,
 emp5.EmployeeName as receiver_by
 FROM Form f
    INNER JOIN Employee emp1 ON emp1.Form_EmployeeID= f.EmployeeID
    INNER JOIN Employee emp2 ON emp2.AgreementBy= f.EmployeeID
    INNER JOIN Employee emp3 ON emp3.Verificationby= f.EmployeeID
    INNER JOIN Employee emp4 ON emp4.Validateby= f.EmployeeID
    INNER JOIN Employee emp5 ON emp5.receiver= f.EmployeeID
 where Form.FormID = '$id'
```

Comment: i have tried this one too but i still got this message --> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'emp2.EmployeeName as agreement_by emp3.EmployeeName as verification_by ' at line 3